# ¿Cómo usar jQuery en Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-2.0

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de utilizar jQuery en Angular 2? 
Por ejemplo para inicializar elementos de materialize o bootstrap como *pushpin*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.tabs-wrapper .row').pushpin({ top: $('.tabs-wrapper').offset().top });
});
```

Comment: Sería para usarlo junto a TypeScript ;)
Siempre ando con "ñapas" y no sé si hay una forma correcta de hacerlo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usar *jQuery* de *Angular2* es una brisa en comparación con ***ng1***. Si está utilizando *TypeScript*, puede hacer referencia a la definición de tipos de letra *jQuery*.

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from   '@angular/core';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;

@Component({
selector: 'ng-chosen',
template: `<select #selectElem>
    <option *ngFor="#item of items" [value]="item" [selected]="item ===     selectedValue">{{item}} option</option>
    </select>
    <h4> {{selectedValue}}</h4>`
})
export class NgChosenComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('selectElem') el:ElementRef;
items = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];
selectedValue = 'Second';

ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement)
        .chosen()
        .on('change', (e, args) => {
            this.selectedValue = args.selected;
        });
    }
}
bootstrap(NgChosenComponent);
```

Para instalar *jQuery* en su aplicación de *Angular 2* haga esto.

```
tsd install jquery --save
or
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres usar `JQuery` desde `Typescript` (con Angular 2 o con cualquier otra cosa), lo mas fácil es instalar `typings` usando `npm`

```
npm install typings --global
```

o bien

```
npm install typings --save
```

y luego instalar las definiciones `Typescript` para `jquery`.

```
typings install dt~jquery --save
```

El prefijo `dt~` viene de [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/), un repositorio centralizado de definiciones `typescript` para las librerías más comunes.

Finalmente añades `jquery` a tu pagina principal y listo.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

La mejor forma de usar Jquery en angular 2 es installandolo en el proyecto y asegurarse que en package.json, quede configurado. Para utlizar junto a bootstrap en el cual es requerimiento para usarlo, se debe configurar el angular-cli.json

installa jquery (con --save se configura el package.json automaticamente)

```
npm install jquery --save
```

configura el angular-cli.json

```
"scripts":['../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', ...],
```

asegurarse que el jquery esta bien configurado en las dependencias en package.json

```
"dependencies":{...
    "jquery": "^3.2.1", ...}
```

si se utiliza junto con bootstrap, para que los estilos de funcionen correctamente, se debe configurar el "styles" en angular-cli.json y ponerlo despues del jquery en "scripts"

Answer (score 1):

puedes usarla de la siguiente manera, primero necesita instalar jquery

```
 npm install jquery
```

en tu archivo de componente

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

despues lo usas como siempre, es lo mas practico a mi parecer.

Saludos